# Repeat a input line until valid input is given

Tags: python

I'm making one of those really old text games.

I give the player two options.

1. Run.
2. Stay.

I let them choose like this:

```
Run = input("Do you:
                     1. Run
                     2. Stay.")
```

Then, an `if` statement saying if they choose option:

1. then more stuff prints. else if,
2. then more stuff prints.

Then we get to my problem.

If they enter something other than choice 1 and 2, then I want it to repeat the question until they finally choose either option 1 or 2.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `while` loop.

Comment: So? Have you tried anything? Done any research? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761

Comment: @TheRedEmerald, you should include that in your post, and explain why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I tried this before. while BreakFree!="1" or "2":

Comment: Well that's just a *different* trivial duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/3001761. Learn to do some research and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a while loop like so:

```
while Run not in ["Run", "stay", "1", "2"]:
    Run = input("not an option, try again:")
```

Comment: make the choice as `["1", "2"]` based on users code

Comment: I'll try it out immediately. Thanks!

Comment: also, could I use != instead of not in

Comment: @TheRedEmerald no you couldn't, that would compare for equality not containment.

Comment: actually, `!=` would check whether `Run` was not equal to the whole list

Comment: Uh, just ran this. And it works! Thanks! But just one tiny question, I put these before the if and elif script right, because right now it's giving me nothing as output even though I have an output that works if you choose option 1 or 2.

Comment: Yup, I tried it out, it  has to go before. Thanks :P